# Sometimes errors while I compile and sometimes not

Tags: latex

A strange thing is happening to my latex document in overleaf, sometimes when I compile everything works fine and I do not get an important error at al. But when I recompile exactly the same latex code two other things could happen:

First scenario:
I recompile and he does not even make a PDF, than this error pops up:
[image: Scenario 1]

Second scenario:
I recompile and he does not match the reference with citations I made in the text (which when I recompile it works and I'm 100% sure they are in the reference.

[image]

My code of the text.tex is:

```
%
% TU/e Style Master Thesis template for LaTeX
%
% Public version 1.0
% 2010 - 2013 Thijs Nugteren and Joos Buijs
%
% THIS IS THE MAIN FILE (i.e. compile this file, compiling the others directly won't work)
%
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{report}

%all the other includes etc. are done in the thesis.sty file.
\usepackage{thesis}

%
% These commands need to be defined in order to produce a correct and personalized document
%
\newcommand{\shortdoctitle}{Master's Thesis}
\newcommand{\doctitle}{}
\newcommand{\docsubtitle}{Master Thesis}

\newcommand{\me}{}
\newcommand{\keywords}{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3}
\newcommand{\version}{Draft version}
\newcommand{\monthYear}{Month 2022}

%Be sure to use all the titles for your committee members!!! (their names show up on the very first page!)
\newcommand{\firstCommitteeMember}{}
\newcommand{\secondCommitteeMember}{}
\newcommand{\thirdCommitteeMember}{}

\author{\me}

%
% PDF settings
%
\hypersetup
{
    pdfauthor={\me},
    pdftitle={\shortdoctitle},
    pdfsubject={\doctitle},
    pdfkeywords={\keywords}
}

\begin{document}

%use this include for PDF and distribution versions
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{titlepage}

\normalsize

\clearemptydoublepage

%Sometimes line numbers are nice, uncomment the next line to enable:
%\linenumbers

%It could be handy to have a list of todos and brainstorms in your thesis
%\chapter*{*General todos*}\todo{remove this chapter}
%\input{chapters/general_todos}

%\chapter*{*Brainstorm results*}\todo{remove this chapter}
%\input{chapters/brainstorm_results}

\chapter*{Abstract}\label{chapter:abstract}
\input{chapters/abstract}

\clearemptydoublepage

%An executive summary if you want:
%\chapter*{Executive summary}\label{chapter:executive_summary}
%\input{chapters/executive_summary}

%\clearemptydoublepage


\chapter*{Preface}\label{chapter:preface}
\input{chapters/preface}

\clearemptydoublepage

\tableofcontents

\clearemptydoublepage

\listoffigures

\clearemptydoublepage

\listoftables

\clearemptydoublepage

\lstlistoflistings

\clearemptydoublepage

\chapter{Introduction}\label{chapter:introduction}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%from here on, start the 'real' page numbering, from 1, with normal digits
\input{chapters/introduction}

\clearemptydoublepage

\chapter{Theoretical Background}\label{chapter:Theoretical_Background}
\input{chapters/Theoretical_Background}

\clearemptydoublepage

\chapter{Multi-Criteria Decision Framework}\label{chapter:first_real_chapter}
\input{chapters/MCDA}

\clearemptydoublepage

\chapter{Simulation Model}\label{chapter:SimulationModel}
\input{chapters/SimulationModel}

\clearemptydoublepage

\chapter{Conclusions}\label{chapter:conclusions}
\input{chapters/conclusions}

\clearemptydoublepage

%Choose a good bibliography style, plain would do often, but these might be nice too
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}

\clearemptydoublepage

\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\input{appendices/main}

\end{document}
```

It is always happening in the same order after recompiling:

- first works
- second some citiations are lost
- total error and won't compile

Edit adding the bibliography code:

```
%Capitalization is very important in references. Be sure to do a double {{ and }} to keep the capitalization of your text in tact.
%Also pay attention to the sorting on last name in the case of complex Dutch names. F.i.: "Aalst, W.M.P. van der and ..." makes it sort under A
@MASTERSTHESIS{MScBuijs2010,
  author = {Buijs, J.C.A.M.},
  title = {{Mapping Data Sources to XES in a Generic Way}},
  school = {{Eindhoven University of Technology}},
  year = {2010},
  file = {Master thesis Joos 2010:C\:\\Users\\jbuijs.TUE\\Documents\\PhD\\Resources\\thesis_JBuijs_final.pdf:PDF},
  keywords = {XES, event log, data, joos, master thesis},
  url = {http://www.processmining.org/_media/xesame/xesma_thesis_final.pdf}
}

@MASTERSTHESIS{MScNugteren2010,
  author = {Nugteren, G.M.},
  title = {{Process Model Simplification}},
  school = {{Eindhoven University of Technology}},
  year = {2010},
  url = {http://alexandria.tue.nl/extra1/afstversl/wsk-i/nugteren2010.pdf}
}

@article{benzidia2019investigating,
  title={Investigating automation and AGV in healthcare logistics: a case study based approach},
  author={Benzidia, Smail and Ageron, Blandine and Bentahar, Omar and Husson, Julien},
  journal={International Journal of Logistics Research and Applications},
  volume={22},
  number={3},
  pages={273--293},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{granlund2013automation,
  title={Automation in healthcare internal logistics: a case study on practice and potential},
  author={Granlund, Anna and Wiktorsson, Magnus},
  journal={International Journal of Innovation and Technology Management},
  volume={10},
  number={03},
  pages={1340012},
  year={2013},
  publisher={World Scientific}
}

@article{volland2017material,
  title={Material logistics in hospitals: a literature review},
  author={Volland, Jonas and F{\"u}gener, Andreas and Schoenfelder, Jan and Brunner, Jens O},
  journal={Omega},
  volume={69},
  pages={82--101},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@inproceedings{kritchanchai2018develop,
  title={Develop a strategy for improving healthcare logistics performance},
  author={Kritchanchai, Duangpun and Hoeur, Soriya and Engelseth, Per},
  booktitle={Supply Chain Forum: An International Journal},
  volume={19},
  pages={55--69},
  year={2018},
  organization={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{bourlakis2011understanding,
  title={Understanding the UK hospital supply chain in an era of patient choice},
  author={Bourlakis, M and Clear, F and Patten, L},
  journal={Journal of Marketing Management},
  volume={27},
  number={3-4},
  pages={401--423},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{PEDAN2017665,
title = {Implementation of Automated Guided Vehicle System in Healthcare Facility},
journal = {Procedia Engineering},
volume = {192},
pages = {665-670},
year = {2017},
note = {12th international scientific conference of young scientists on sustainable, modern and safe transport},
issn = {1877-7058},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.proeng.2017.06.115},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705817326619},
author = {Marko Pedan and Milan Gregor and Dariusz Plinta},
keywords = {AGV, healthcare, improvement, simulation, efficiency},
abstract = {The article deals with the use of automated guided vehicle (AGV) system in the hospital. This paper provides the requirements and technical specifications of AGV cart designed for healthcare facility. The second part describes the application and benefits of AGV implementation in selected health care facility gained from computer simulation that is used as a verification tool. This part also contains the economic evaluation of this implementation and summary of further investments related to this technology.}
}

@inproceedings{bhosekar2018simulation,
  title={Simulation Optimization of Automated Guided Vehicle System in a Health Care Facility},
  author={Bhosekar, Amogh S and Gilstrap, Kade and Isik, Tugce and Eksioglu, Sandra D and Allen, Robert},
  booktitle={IIE Annual Conference. Proceedings},
  pages={263--268},
  year={2018},
  organization={Institute of Industrial and Systems Engineers (IISE)}
}

@inproceedings{niemela2017social,
  title={A social service robot in a shopping mall: expectations of the management, retailers and consumers},
  author={Niemel{\"a}, Marketta and Heikkil{\"a}, P{\"a}ivi and Lammi, Hanna},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the Companion of the 2017 ACM/IEEE International Conference on Human-Robot Interaction},
  pages={227--228},
  year={2017}
}

@article{salfer2017finances,
  title={Finances and returns for robotic dairies},
  author={Salfer, JA and Minegishi, K and Lazarus, W and Berning, E and Endres, MI},
  journal={Journal of Dairy Science},
  volume={100},
  number={9},
  pages={7739--7749},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{SER,
  title={Juni 2020 Zorg voor de toekomst},
  author={SER},
  journal={},
  year={2020},
  publisher={SER}
}

@article{Vergrijzing,
  title={De sociale staat van Nederland 2019},
  author={Sociaal en cultureel planbureau},
  journal={},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Sociaal en cultureel planbureau
  
  }
}

@article{soraa2021social,
  title={Social domestication of service robots: The secret lives of Automated Guided Vehicles (AGVs) at a Norwegian hospital},
  author={S{\o}raa, Roger A and Fostervold, Marianne E},
  journal={International journal of human-computer studies},
  volume={152},
  pages={102627},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{yatsalo2015decerns,
  title={Decerns: a framework for multi-criteria decision analysis},
  author={Yatsalo, Boris and Didenko, Vladimir and Gritsyuk, Sergey and Sullivan, Terry},
  journal={International Journal of Computational Intelligence Systems},
  volume={8},
  number={3},
  pages={467--489},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}


@article{davina2012development,
  title={Development of a simulation-based tool for designing AGV-systems for hospital logistics},
  author={Davina, K},
  journal={},
  year={2012}
}

@article{fragapane2019agent,
  title={An agent-based simulation approach to model hospital logistics},
  author={Fragapane, GI and Zhang, Cevin and Sgarbossa, Fabio and Strandhagen, Jan Ola},
  journal={International Journal of Simulation Modelling},
  volume={18},
  number={4},
  pages={654--665},
  year={2019}
}

@article{uhlemann2017digital,
  title={The digital twin: Realizing the cyber-physical production system for industry 4.0},
  author={Uhlemann, Thomas H-J and Lehmann, Christian and Steinhilper, Rolf},
  journal={Procedia Cirp},
  volume={61},
  pages={335--340},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{lu2020digital,
  title={Digital Twin-driven smart manufacturing: Connotation, reference model, applications and research issues},
  author={Lu, Yuqian and Liu, Chao and Kevin, I and Wang, Kai and Huang, Huiyue and Xu, Xun},
  journal={Robotics and Computer-Integrated Manufacturing},
  volume={61},
  pages={101837},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}


@article{QuickscanUMCU,
  title={Logistieke quick scan UMCU},
  author={Ham, Annelies},
  journal={},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Squrious}
}

@inproceedings{fulop2005introduction,
  title={Introduction to decision making methods},
  author={F{\"u}l{\"o}p, J{\'a}nos},
  booktitle={BDEI-3 workshop, Washington},
  pages={1--15},
  year={2005}
}

@article{triantaphyllou1998multi,
  title={Multi-criteria decision making: an operations research approach},
  author={Triantaphyllou, Evangelos and Shu, Bo and Sanchez, S Nieto and Ray, Tony},
  journal={Encyclopedia of electrical and electronics engineering},
  volume={15},
  number={1998},
  pages={175--186},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Citeseer}
}

@article{zavadskas2014state,
  title={State of art surveys of overviews on MCDM/MADM methods},
  author={Zavadskas, Edmundas Kazimieras and Turskis, Zenonas and Kildien{\.e}, Simona},
  journal={Technological and economic development of economy},
  volume={20},
  number={1},
  pages={165--179},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{gebre2021multi,
  title={Multi-criteria decision-making methods to address water allocation problems: A systematic review},
  author={Gebre, Sintayehu Legesse and Cattrysse, Dirk and Van Orshoven, Jos},
  journal={Water},
  volume={13},
  number={2},
  pages={125},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}

@article{dante2019application,
  title={Application of Fuzzy AHP and TOPSIS methods for a Foreign Direct Investment in the aluminium industry sector},
  author={Dante, Elena},
  journal={},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Universit{\`a} Ca'Foscari Venezia}
}

@article{chang1996applications,
  title={Applications of the extent analysis method on fuzzy AHP},
  author={Chang, Da-Yong},
  journal={European journal of operational research},
  volume={95},
  number={3},
  pages={649--655},
  year={1996},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{vargas1990overview,
  title={An overview of the analytic hierarchy process and its applications},
  author={Vargas, Luis G},
  journal={European journal of operational research},
  volume={48},
  number={1},
  pages={2--8},
  year={1990},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{afshari2010simple,
  title={Simple additive weighting approach to personnel selection problem},
  author={Afshari, Alireza and Mojahed, Majid and Yusuff, Rosnah Mohd},
  journal={International Journal of Innovation, Management and Technology},
  volume={1},
  number={5},
  pages={511},
  year={2010},
  publisher={IACSIT Press}
}

@article{heydaryan2018safety,
  title={Safety design and development of a human-robot collaboration assembly process in the automotive industry},
  author={Heydaryan, Sahar and Suaza Bedolla, Joel and Belingardi, Giovanni},
  journal={Applied Sciences},
  volume={8},
  number={3},
  pages={344},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}

@article{velmurugan2011multi,
  title={Multi criteria decision making to select the suitable method for the preparation of nanoparticles using an analytical hierarchy process},
  author={Velmurugan, R and Selvamuthukumar, S and Manavalan, R},
  journal={Die Pharmazie-An International Journal of Pharmaceutical Sciences},
  volume={66},
  number={11},
  pages={836--842},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Avoxa-Mediengruppe Deutscher Apotheker GmbH}
}

@article{harker1987theory,
  title={The theory of ratio scale estimation: Saaty's analytic hierarchy process},
  author={Harker, Patrick T and Vargas, Luis G},
  journal={Management science},
  volume={33},
  number={11},
  pages={1383--1403},
  year={1987},
  publisher={INFORMS}
}

@inproceedings{chen2006evaluating,
  title={Evaluating the selection of logistics centre location using fuzzy MCDM model based on entropy weight},
  author={Chen, Yan and Qu, Lili},
  booktitle={2006 6th World Congress on Intelligent Control and Automation},
  volume={2},
  pages={7128--7132},
  year={2006},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{dursun2011fuzzy,
  title={A fuzzy MCDM approach for health-care waste management},
  author={Dursun, Mehtap and Karsak, E Ertugrul and Karadayi, Melis Almula},
  journal={International Journal of Industrial and Manufacturing Engineering},
  volume={5},
  number={1},
  pages={176--182},
  year={2011}
}

@article{mathew2018comparison,
  title={Comparison of new multi-criteria decision making methods for material handling equipment selection},
  author={Mathew, Manoj and Sahu, Sagar},
  journal={Management Science Letters},
  volume={8},
  number={3},
  pages={139--150},
  year={2018}
}

@article{alamerew2020multi,
  title={A multi-criteria evaluation method of product-level circularity strategies},
  author={Alamerew, Yohannes A and Kambanou, Marianna Lena and Sakao, Tomohiko and Brissaud, Daniel},
  journal={Sustainability},
  volume={12},
  number={12},
  pages={5129},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}

@article{ozdaugouglu2007comparison,
  title={Comparison of AHP and fuzzy AHP for the multi-criteria decision making processes with linguistic evaluations},
  author={{\"O}zda{\u{g}}o{\u{g}}lu, A{\c{s}}k{\i}n and {\"O}zda{\u{g}}o{\u{g}}lu, G{\"u}zin},
  journal={{\.I}stanbul Ticaret {\"U}niversitesi Fen Bilimleri Dergisi},
  volume={6},
  number={11},
  pages={65--85},
  year={2007}
}

@article{ribeiro1996fuzzy,
  title={Fuzzy multiple attribute decision making: a review and new preference elicitation techniques},
  author={Ribeiro, Rita Almeida},
  journal={Fuzzy sets and systems},
  volume={78},
  number={2},
  pages={155--181},
  year={1996},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{ligus2017evaluation,
  title={Evaluation of economic, social and environmental effects of low-emission energy technologies development in Poland: A multi-criteria analysis with application of a fuzzy analytic hierarchy process (FAHP)},
  author={Ligus, Magdalena},
  journal={Energies},
  volume={10},
  number={10},
  pages={1550},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}

@article{tang2005application,
  title={Application and development of a fuzzy analytic hierarchy process within a capital investment study},
  author={Tang, Yu-Cheng and Beynon, Malcolm J and others},
  journal={Journal of economics and management},
  volume={1},
  number={2},
  pages={207--230},
  year={2005}
}

@article{milovsevic2020implementation,
  title={Implementation of adjusted fuzzy AHP method in the assessment for reuse of industrial buildings},
  author={Milo{\v{s}}evi{\'c}, Du{\v{s}}an M and Milo{\v{s}}evi{\'c}, Mimica R and Simjanovi{\'c}, Du{\v{s}}an J},
  journal={Mathematics},
  volume={8},
  number={10},
  pages={1697},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}

@article{srichetta2012applying,
  title={Applying fuzzy analytic hierarchy process to evaluate and select product of notebook computers},
  author={Srichetta, Phanarut and Thurachon, Wannasiri},
  journal={International Journal of Modeling and Optimization},
  volume={2},
  number={2},
  pages={168},
  year={2012},
  publisher={IACSIT Press}
}

@inproceedings{rossetti1998mobile,
  title={Mobile robot simulation of clinical laboratory deliveries},
  author={Rossetti, Manuel D and Kumar, Amit and Felder, Robin A},
  booktitle={1998 Winter Simulation Conference. Proceedings (Cat. No. 98CH36274)},
  volume={2},
  pages={1415--1422},
  year={1998},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{rossetti2001multi,
  title={Multi-objective analysis of hospital delivery systems},
  author={Rossetti, Manuel D and Selandari, Francesco},
  journal={Computers \& Industrial Engineering},
  volume={41},
  number={3},
  pages={309--333},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@inproceedings{yen2018nurses,
  title={Nurses’ time allocation and multitasking of nursing activities: a time motion study},
  author={Yen, Po-Yin and Kellye, Marjorie and Lopetegui, Marcelo and Saha, Abhijoy and Loversidge, Jacqueline and Chipps, Esther M and Gallagher-Ford, Lynn and Buck, Jacalyn},
  booktitle={AMIA Annual Symposium Proceedings},
  volume={2018},
  pages={1137},
  year={2018},
  organization={American Medical Informatics Association}
}

@inproceedings{fragapane2020autonomous,
  title={Autonomous mobile robots in hospital logistics},
  author={Fragapane, Giuseppe and Hvolby, Hans-Henrik and Sgarbossa, Fabio and Strandhagen, Jan Ola},
  booktitle={IFIP International Conference on Advances in Production Management Systems},
  pages={672--679},
  year={2020},
  organization={Springer}
}

@article{kriegel2013advanced,
  title={Advanced services in hospital logistics in the German health service sector},
  author={Kriegel, Johannes and Jehle, Franziska and Dieck, Marcel and Mallory, Patricia},
  journal={Logistics Research},
  volume={6},
  number={2},
  pages={47--56},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{borges2020simulation,
  title={Simulation-based analysis of lean practices implementation on the supply chain of a public hospital},
  author={Borges, Gabriela Aline and Tortorella, Guilherme Luz and Mart{\'\i}nez, Felipe and Thurer, Matthias},
  journal={Production},
  volume={30},
  year={2020},
  publisher={SciELO Brasil}
}

@inproceedings{borshchev2004system,
  title={From system dynamics and discrete event to practical agent based modeling: reasons, techniques, tools},
  author={Borshchev, Andrei and Filippov, Alexei},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 22nd international conference of the system dynamics society},
  volume={22},
  pages={25--29},
  year={2004},
  organization={Citeseer}
}

@article{owen2010simulation,
  title={Simulation in the supply chain context: matching the simulation tool to the problem},
  author={Owen, Christopher and Albores, Pavel and Greasley, Andrew and Love, Doug},
  year={2010},
  journal={},
  publisher={Operational Research Society}
}

@article{fragapane2021autonomous,
  title={Autonomous material transportation in hospital intralogistics},
  author={Fragapane, Giuseppe Ismael},
  journal={Water},
  year={2021},
  publisher={NTNU}
}

@inproceedings{sheridan2000human,
  title={Human vs. automation in responding to failures: An expected-value analysis},
  author={Sheridan, Thomas B and Parasuraman, Raja},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the Human Factors and Ergonomics Society Annual Meeting},
  volume={44},
  pages={1--4},
  year={2000},
  organization={SAGE Publications Sage CA: Los Angeles, CA}
}


@article{karabegovic2015application,
  title={The application of service robots for logistics in manufacturing processes.},
  author={Karabegovi{\'c}, I and Karabegovi{\'c}, E and Mahmi{\'c}, M and Husak, E},
  journal={Advances in Production Engineering \& Management},
  volume={10},
  number={4},
  year={2015}
}
```

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]? We don't have access to your local files and special packages, so we can't test the code you showed. My guess is that the error is in one or more of the citations. On the first run, latex just collects which references you want. Then in the next step bibtex is run to get these references from your bib file. In the next latex run, latex tries to insert these references and encounters an error and aborts the run leaving some auxiliary files in a wonky state. On the next run, latex tries to use these wonky auxiliary files and everything explodes.

Comment: Bottom line: we need to see the code to tell you what to fix

Comment: I broke it down by deleting everything one by one and testing if the error still occured, I found out that the error when i clear my whole bibliography and delete it, the errors disappears, as soon as I add something to the bibliography, the error returns

Comment: I've added the code of the bibliography to the original post, but even when I only add one source it already start erroring.

Comment: Another thing is when I compile fast, it works without error.

Comment: It is nice to hear that you narrowed it down to the bibliography. Can you please update your question to post a [mre] which we can use to reproduce your problem? We can't compile the code from your question. It does have custom packages like `thesis`, whcih we don't have and tons of included file we don't have. Just adding your bibliography to an otherwise empty file works without problems